# How would I receive all data from nested arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb

Currently, I have this dataset inside my functional component and it works fine.

```
const data = {
      across: {
        1: {
          clue: 'number1',
          answer: 'number1',
          row: 1,
          col: 0,
        },
        2: {
        clue: 'number2',
        answer: 'number2',
        row: 3,
        col: 1,
       },
      },
...etc
}
```

I've inserted the following into MongoDB in an attempt to make it an embedded array with objects that have arrays (yes, I know it's a bit convoluted but I'm trying to retain the same logic as the first dataset).

```
{
    "across" : [
    {
    "1" : [
    {
    "clue" : "number1",
    "answer" : "number1",
    "row" : "1",
    "col" : "0"
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "2" : [
    {
    "clue" : "number2",
    "answer" : "number2",
    "row" : "3",
    "col" : "1"
    }
    ]
    },
...etc
}
```

I used the following function to call it from the database:

```
    const data = await data_db.collection('data').find({}).toArray();
    return data;
```

However, when I tried to retrieve it from there, this appears.

```
[
  {
    _id: 5f65acf92bd6f113073e56e2,
    across: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  },
]
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it an issue with how I am calling it or is it an issue with my data model in MongoDB? Thanks in advance :)